# Accessing global variables via the window object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, global-variables, language-design

So I know that you could previously access any variable using the variable name in a string form via the `window` object, like this:

```
variable = "test";
alert(window["variable"]); // Alerts "test"
```

And that works.

But when you do this, it doesn't work:

```
var variable = "test";
alert(window["variable"]); // Alerts undefined
```

1. Why does the only difference, the `var`, cause it to return `undefined`?
2. Is this a recent change to JavaScript?
3. Is there a way around it? If so, what?

Also, please note that I am using version 55.0.2883.87 m of Chrome.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably this code is running inside a closure, so `variable` is a local variable, and not a global one.

Comment: Perhaps, but wouldn't it be the other way around? Seeing as it returns undefined only when using the `var` statement, which marks the variable as global, right?

Comment: `var` defines a variable in the current scope (a local variable in a closure). Undeclared variables are implicit globals (unless the code is in strict mode, which makes them errors).

Comment: Oh my god, for all these years I thought that `var` was to state a global variable! Thank you! But that said, how would I work around the issue if the variable was local? Or is there no way?

Comment: I would recommend staying away from global variables (outside of packages in you import).

Comment: You can't really, and you shouldn't really have to. If you want, you can set whatever variables you want to be able to lookup by name on an object.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'm writing a library that accesses a variable supplied using the variable name in string form. So I guess that I'll just need to say to those using the library that they're variables have to be global?

Comment: Global variables can cause all sorts of naming conflicts and should always be avoided.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I don't think that there is another way, but is there? Here is the [library](https://ioninja.github.io/vaultjs/vault.js) (so far) and an [example](https://ioninja.github.io/vaultjs/examples/counter.html).

Comment: Be obvious, if you want to declare global variable, do `window.variable = "test";`, then, always access them by `window.variable`. Other wise, do `var variable = "test";`.